# How to get space between tables in html?

Tags: html

How do I create space in HTML between tables?

What tag do I need for that?

[image: an image of the borders between two horizontally stacked html tables showing the tables right next to each other]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[selector] + [selector]` css selector to specify any table that comes right after another table. In this case, `table + table { margin-left: 1em; }`, where you replace `1em` with whatever size you want to specify.

Example code:

```css
table {
  display: inline;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td, th {
  border: thin solid black;
}
/* the important part: */
table + table {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr><th>column 1</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>first item</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<thead><tr><th>column 1</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>another item</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```